# $\sin(ωt) + \sin(ωt+\Delta\theta) + \sin(ωt+2\,\Delta\theta) + \cdots + \sin(ωt+\overline{n-1}\,\Delta\theta) ={}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

How will we add this series? 
Any simple process?
This is one of the equation derived from the equation to find intesity of ray at any particular point in Fraunhofer diffraction.
I think this can be solved using simple series but my teacher told any process involving Imaginary part iota, which I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint.

Thy to multiply it by $2\sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}$ and use $$2\sin\alpha\sin\beta=\cos(\alpha-\beta)-\cos(\alpha+\beta).$$

\begin{align}
& \sin\omega t + \sin(\omega t+∆θ) + \sin(ωt+2∆θ) + \cdots + \sin(ωt+(n-1)∆θ) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{2\sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}\sin\omega t +2\sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2} \sin(\omega t+∆θ)+ \cdots + 2\sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}\sin(ωt+(n-1)∆θ)}{2\sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \tfrac{\cos\left(\omega t-\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\omega t + \frac{\Delta\theta}{2}\right) +\cos\left(\omega t+\frac{\Delta\theta}{2} \right) - \cos\left(\omega t+\frac{3\Delta\theta}{2} \right) + \cdots+\cos\left(\omega t+\left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)\Delta\theta\right)-\cos\left(\omega t+\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\Delta\right)\theta\right)}{2\sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\cos\left(\omega t-\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\omega t + \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\Delta\theta\right)}{2\sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please solve it for me?

Comment: this is always been my favourite solution!

Comment: Yes, I also like it! @Ayush Bhardwaj I added something.

Comment: ' Thanks, That's very helpful and Simple explanations as well! '

Comment: @Ayush Bhardwaj You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

> Find the value of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(a+kt)$.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(a+kt)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{i(a+kt)}-e^{-i(a+kt)}}{2i}\\=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{i(a+kt)}}{2i}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{-i(a+kt)}}{2i}\\=\frac{e^{ia}}{2i}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{ikt}-\frac{e^{-ia}}{2i}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-ikt}\\=\frac{e^{ia}}{2i}\frac{1-e^{int}}{1-e^{it}}-\frac{e^{-ia}}{2i}\frac{1-e^{-int}}{1-e^{-it}}\end{align}$$

Can you do next steps?